# Convert JSON to prometheus readable format

Tags: java, json, prometheus, jq, metrics

This is my API response in JSON format. Not able to convert it to Prometheus format using jq or any other better approach to capture the metrics on Prometheus UI.

```json
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "gauges": {
    "gc.G1-Old-Generation.count": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "gc.G1-Old-Generation.time": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "gc.G1-Young-Generation.count": {
      "value": 30
    },
    "gc.G1-Young-Generation.time": {
      "value": 427
    },
    "jvm.name": {
      "value": "7@hubstorage"
    },
    "jvm.uptime": {
      "value": 44799
    },
    "jvm.vendor": {
      "value": "Azul Systems, Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-LTS (11)"
    },
    "memory.heap.committed": {
      "value": 208666624
    },
    "memory.heap.init": {
      "value": 65011712
    },
    "memory.heap.max": {
      "value": 1035993088
    },
    "memory.heap.usage": {
      "value": 0.11967882164094129
    },
    "memory.heap.used": {
      "value": 123986432
    },
    "memory.non-heap.committed": {
      "value": 114434048
    },
    "memory.non-heap.init": {
      "value": 7667712
    },
    "memory.non-heap.max": {
      "value": -1
    },
    "memory.non-heap.usage": {
      "value": -108223704
    },
    "memory.non-heap.used": {
      "value": 108223704
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-nmethods'.committed": {
      "value": 2555904
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-nmethods'.init": {
      "value": 2555904
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-nmethods'.max": {
      "value": 5832704
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-nmethods'.usage": {
      "value": 0.23114905196629212
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-nmethods'.used": {
      "value": 1348224
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-profiled-nmethods'.committed": {
      "value": 3670016
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-profiled-nmethods'.init": {
      "value": 2555904
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-profiled-nmethods'.max": {
      "value": 122912768
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-profiled-nmethods'.usage": {
      "value": 0.029816007398027193
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'non-profiled-nmethods'.used": {
      "value": 3664768
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'profiled-nmethods'.committed": {
      "value": 12517376
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'profiled-nmethods'.init": {
      "value": 2555904
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'profiled-nmethods'.max": {
      "value": 122912768
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'profiled-nmethods'.usage": {
      "value": 0.10141253998933618
    },
    "memory.pools.CodeHeap-'profiled-nmethods'.used": {
      "value": 12464896
    },
    "memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.committed": {
      "value": 12267520
    },
    "memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.init": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.max": {
      "value": 1073741824
    },
    "memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.usage": {
      "value": 0.010960675776004791
    },
    "memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.used": {
      "value": 11768936
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.committed": {
      "value": 118489088
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.init": {
      "value": 15728640
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.max": {
      "value": -1
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.usage": {
      "value": 0.6548672566371682
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.used": {
      "value": 77594624
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.committed": {
      "value": 82837504
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.init": {
      "value": 49283072
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.max": {
      "value": 1035993088
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.usage": {
      "value": 0.0376950159729251
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.used": {
      "value": 39051776
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.committed": {
      "value": 7340032
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.init": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.max": {
      "value": -1
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.usage": {
      "value": 1
    },
    "memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.used": {
      "value": 7340032
    },
    "memory.pools.Metaspace.committed": {
      "value": 83423232
    },
    "memory.pools.Metaspace.init": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "memory.pools.Metaspace.max": {
      "value": -1
    },
    "memory.pools.Metaspace.usage": {
      "value": 0.9467012738130309
    },
    "memory.pools.Metaspace.used": {
      "value": 78976880
    },
    "memory.total.committed": {
      "value": 323100672
    },
    "memory.total.init": {
      "value": 72679424
    },
    "memory.total.max": {
      "value": 1035993087
    },
    "memory.total.used": {
      "value": 232210136
    },
    "threads.blocked.count": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "threads.count": {
      "value": 34
    },
    "threads.daemon.count": {
      "value": 14
    },
    "threads.deadlock.count": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "threads.deadlocks": {
      "value": []
    },
    "threads.new.count": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "threads.runnable.count": {
      "value": 11
    },
    "threads.terminated.count": {
      "value": 0
    },
    "threads.timed_waiting.count": {
      "value": 17
    },
    "threads.waiting.count": {
      "value": 6
    }
  },
  "counters": {
    "counter": {
      "count": 1
    }
  },
  "histograms": {
    "histogram": {
      "count": 3,
      "max": 100,
      "mean": 41.66666666666666,
      "min": 5,
      "p50": 20,
      "p75": 100,
      "p95": 100,
      "p98": 100,
      "p99": 100,
      "p999": 100,
      "stddev": 41.69998667732268
    }
  },
  "meters": {
    "meter": {
      "count": 201,
      "m15_rate": 38.666674566183616,
      "m1_rate": 22.433012859955905,
      "m5_rate": 35.77324719371856,
      "mean_rate": 4.944024762580441,
      "units": "events/second"
    }
  },
  "timers": {}
}
```

Getting the following error on Prometheus:
"INVALID" is not a valid start token

Comment: Looks like here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844617/prometheus-json-metrics

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
paths(scalars) as $p 
| "\($p|join("_")|gsub("[^\\w_.-]";""))=\(getpath($p)|@sh)"
```

```
$ jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | "\($p|join("_")|gsub("[^\\w_.-]";""))=\(getpath($p)|@sh)"' file.json 

version='3.0.0'
gauges_gc.G1-Old-Generation.count_value=0
gauges_gc.G1-Old-Generation.time_value=0
gauges_gc.G1-Young-Generation.count_value=30
gauges_gc.G1-Young-Generation.time_value=427
gauges_jvm.name_value='7@hubstorage'
gauges_jvm.uptime_value=44799
gauges_jvm.vendor_value='Azul Systems, Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-LTS (11)'
gauges_memory.heap.committed_value=208666624
gauges_memory.heap.init_value=65011712
gauges_memory.heap.max_value=1035993088
gauges_memory.heap.usage_value=0.11967882164094129
gauges_memory.heap.used_value=123986432
gauges_memory.non-heap.committed_value=114434048
gauges_memory.non-heap.init_value=7667712
gauges_memory.non-heap.max_value=-1
gauges_memory.non-heap.usage_value=-108223704
gauges_memory.non-heap.used_value=108223704
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-nmethods.committed_value=2555904
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-nmethods.init_value=2555904
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-nmethods.max_value=5832704
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-nmethods.usage_value=0.23114905196629212
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-nmethods.used_value=1348224
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-profiled-nmethods.committed_value=3670016
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-profiled-nmethods.init_value=2555904
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-profiled-nmethods.max_value=122912768
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-profiled-nmethods.usage_value=0.029816007398027193
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-non-profiled-nmethods.used_value=3664768
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-profiled-nmethods.committed_value=12517376
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-profiled-nmethods.init_value=2555904
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-profiled-nmethods.max_value=122912768
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-profiled-nmethods.usage_value=0.10141253998933618
gauges_memory.pools.CodeHeap-profiled-nmethods.used_value=12464896
gauges_memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.committed_value=12267520
gauges_memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.init_value=0
gauges_memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.max_value=1073741824
gauges_memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.usage_value=0.010960675776004791
gauges_memory.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.used_value=11768936
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.committed_value=118489088
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.init_value=15728640
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.max_value=-1
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.usage_value=0.6548672566371682
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Eden-Space.used_value=77594624
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.committed_value=82837504
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.init_value=49283072
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.max_value=1035993088
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.usage_value=0.0376950159729251
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Old-Gen.used_value=39051776
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.committed_value=7340032
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.init_value=0
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.max_value=-1
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.usage_value=1
gauges_memory.pools.G1-Survivor-Space.used_value=7340032
gauges_memory.pools.Metaspace.committed_value=83423232
gauges_memory.pools.Metaspace.init_value=0
gauges_memory.pools.Metaspace.max_value=-1
gauges_memory.pools.Metaspace.usage_value=0.9467012738130309
gauges_memory.pools.Metaspace.used_value=78976880
gauges_memory.total.committed_value=323100672
gauges_memory.total.init_value=72679424
gauges_memory.total.max_value=1035993087
gauges_memory.total.used_value=232210136
gauges_threads.blocked.count_value=0
gauges_threads.count_value=34
gauges_threads.daemon.count_value=14
gauges_threads.deadlock.count_value=0
gauges_threads.new.count_value=0
gauges_threads.runnable.count_value=11
gauges_threads.terminated.count_value=0
gauges_threads.timed_waiting.count_value=17
gauges_threads.waiting.count_value=6
counters_counter_count=1
histograms_histogram_count=3
histograms_histogram_max=100
histograms_histogram_mean=41.66666666666666
histograms_histogram_min=5
histograms_histogram_p50=20
histograms_histogram_p75=100
histograms_histogram_p95=100
histograms_histogram_p98=100
histograms_histogram_p99=100
histograms_histogram_p999=100
histograms_histogram_stddev=41.69998667732268
meters_meter_count=201
meters_meter_m15_rate=38.666674566183616
meters_meter_m1_rate=22.433012859955905
meters_meter_m5_rate=35.77324719371856
meters_meter_mean_rate=4.944024762580441
meters_meter_units='events/second'
```